# How to create table to store large data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am developing a VB.NET application that will communicate with an external device over serial port. It is a testing device in which a single lamp will be tested for 2000 hours continuously.

This device will give data pertaining lamp parameter (e.g. current) every 10 seconds, that means I will have 720000 readings per test. This data will be logged into some database for future reference.

I searched on the internet about saving such a big amount of data, but learnt that no database supports these many columns in a single table.

Please guide me as to how to log such a huge data.

Comment: Why do you want to use columns? Try to use lines. If you use indexes smart, it will be very fast.

Comment: Relational databases are called that because of the relations. You would have one table for the tests and one table for the readings. That means that you would have 720,000 records in the readings table related to each record in the test table.

Comment: Can you explain with some example please. I'm totally new to the SQL server or RDBMS.. @jmcilhinney

Comment: You mean you can't find any examples of related tables with a web search?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having multiple columns on the same table, try with multiple rows for each test. ie; for each test, I will insert a new record into the table for that particular Lamp against that particular time slot and you can filter it later. So If you decide to change the Test interval or Duration, you do not need to worry about the table design as it is already designed in such a way that It can store any number of values against any record. I recommend a design like this

[image: Design]

Some sample data for a Lamp for the first 3 tests will be as below

[image: Sample]

Hope This helps

Answer (score 2):

Don't use columns. Use records. One reading = one record. Your table should have columns for a testID, timestamp, and reading value.